# Scheduling a workflow execution in Cloudify

Tags: cloudify

I'm new with cloudify (4.2) and trying to exercise sheduling workflows. On Cloudify Roadmap i found this feature:

> Scheduled Workflow Execution: The ability to schedule a workflow execution at a future time, such as scaling the number of web server VMs at a certain time of the day

But unfortunately i can't find that in the documentation nor a small example on how to do this, what services, policies should i use.

Any hints and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is available now with Cloudify 4.5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that this feature is in development, which is the reason you found it on the Roadmap page, and it will not be found anywhere in the docs either. We don't yet know to which upcoming release this will be added.

If you have any other questions, please head over and ask on the [User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cloudify-users).